# SQL Select based on condition from another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables composing with the following definitions:

```
A
ID | Name    | Description
1  | Bag     | It's a bag
2  | Leather | Leather makes the bag
3  | Website | It's a website
4  | Images  | Just normal images
5  | Text    | Some descriptive text

B
parentID | childID | Quantity
1        | 2       | 5
3        | 4       | 2
3        | 5       | 1
```

I'm trying to find all items in table A which are of level 0 (meaning they have no parent) and then use that to try and find the items in the following levels.

So far I've gotten to this, which I thought would work, but clearly not...

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.ID in (
  SELECT B.parentID
  FROM B
  WHERE (B.childID is NULL)
);
```

If anyone could shed some light on this I'd really appreciate it. Also if there's some must-reads for SQL querying please let me know, I'd be glad to learn more about this, as it's something I struggle with.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've edited the data to hopefully illustrate a little better what I'm trying to achieve. There's several items, some are parents and some are children.

From table B you can tell that to make 1 bag, you need 5 leather (bag is parent of leather with quantity 5). Or that the website is composed of 2 Image and 1 Text (website is parent to both Image quantity 2 and Text quantity 1).
I want to query for the bag and website only, meaning the items in table A which have no parents in table B.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) A.k.a. [mcve].

Comment: So the ID is not matched with anyother id in table B? Can you show sampel data from the tables? Show us some desiered output so we can help  you

Comment: Just edited the main post to hopefully illustrate the problem a little bit better!

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself, basically what I was looking for was this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.ID not in (
SELECT B.childID
FROM B
);
```

This selects all items from A which have no parents (meaning they are not children of any other item).